# How to use the bubble sort and sorting a 2d array with strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d, bubble-sort

I want to have a main program that reads 10 names using `scanf` (maximum 100 characters), saves them to a 2D array (`char[10][100]`) and then calls a function that has the algorithm of the bubblesort and sorts the 2D array. And finally I want the main program to print the sorted 2D array.

The prototype of the function is:

```
void bubble_sort(str[][100]);
```

Can anybody show me the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

void bubble_sort(char str[SIZE][100]);

int main (void) {
    char names[SIZE][100];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Enter names: ");
        scanf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    bubble_sort(names);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf ("%s\n", names[i]);
}

void bubble_sort(char str[SIZE][100]) {
    int i, j, reorder = 0;
    char temp;

    for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = SIZE - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (strcmp(str[j], str[j + 1]) > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, str[j + 1]);
                strcpy(str[j + 1], str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], temp);
                reorder = 1;
            }
        }
        if (reorder == 0)
            return;
    }
}
```

I expect to type 10 names and then get as an output these 10 names in an ascending alphabetical way.

Comment: The prototype to the function is bad; you should tell the function explicitly how many entries there are to sort with an argument.

Comment: well that's what our exercise says...  i am lost

Comment: I suspected as much.  The exercise is not inculcating best practices.  Ah well, not all courses or tutors are created equal.

Comment: can i get some help with this ? I want any code that gives me the result i want, using the bubble sort function.

Comment: You might care to look long and hard at `for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        for (j = SIZE-1; j <=i; j++)` — when does this iterate on the inner loop?  You'll also need to revisit when you set `reorder = 0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my answer, hope it is useful for you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

void bubble_sort(char str[SIZE][100]);

int main (void) 
{
    char names[SIZE][100];
    printf("The max length of name is 99\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("Enter names:");
        scanf("%99s",names[i]);
    }

    bubble_sort (names);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf ("%s\n", names[i]);
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort (char str[SIZE][100])
{
    int i, j;
    char temp[100] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < 10 - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10 - 1 - i; j++) {
             if (strcmp(str[j], str[j + 1]) > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], str[j + 1]);
                strcpy(str[j + 1], temp);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The above program output is:

```
Enter names:ca
Enter names:sd
Enter names:fgg
Enter names:cb
Enter names:dssd
Enter names:hgf
Enter names:jydt
Enter names:jdjy
Enter names:dgr  
Enter names:htr
ca
cb
dgr
dssd
fgg
hgf
htr
jdjy
jydt
sd
```

Comment: A short explanation of the OP's error would help. `scanf("%s",names[i]);` should be protected against overflow as `scanf("%99s",names[i]);` and its return value should be tested for premature end of file.